# Cifrado y descifrado de palabras

Tags: python, django, web

Estoy realizando un programa en Python y necesito realizar el cifrado de una contraseña de un formulario. Mi problema es que el método por defecto de cifrado más popular en Python es Crypt, pero este es para UNIX. Como podría cifrar y descifrar palabras en Windows?

Comment: Hola Richard, ¿Te has mirado la documentación de Django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/passwords/#password-management-in-django? La idea (lo mismo con Crypt) no es cifrar y almacenar la contraseña, es generar y almacenar un hash de ella. https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/182614/15089.

Comment: Richard, no es Encriptar o Desencriptar, es Cifrar o Descifrar. y Yo utilizo el cifrado de django por dejecto en windows y no tengo problemas.

Comment: De forma general, las contraseñas no se desencriptan. Se calcula un hash (algoritmo no reversible) de ellas, usando alguno de los diversos métodos existentes: sha256, sha512, bcrypt, etc; y se guarda en la base de datos. Cuando el usuario introduce su contraseña, se calcula el hash con el mismo método y se compara con la guardada en la base. Si coincide, se le deja acceder.
Si estas necesitando un algoritmo de encriptación/desencriptación, lo cual se usa para cifrar mensajes o información confidencial, está AES.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que estás buscando es passlib, [aquí](https://pypi.org/project/passlib/) encontraras la liga de la documentación, para descargarlo usa `pip install passlib` en Windows PowerShell. En esta [liga](http://blog.tecladocode.com/learn-python-encrypting-passwords-python-flask-and-passlib/) encontraras un breve tutorial de como hacer uso de la librería.

Otra manera muy fácil y en lo personal eficiente es hacer uso de las librerías [hashlib](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/hashlib.html) y [random](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html).